# Remove duplicates from a list using 2 for loops without using (inbuilt functions, temp, new list, enumerate)

Tags: python

```
def remove_dup1(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(1, len(a)):
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[j]
    print(a)
s1 = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,8,7,8]
remove_dup1(s1)
print(s1)
```

from the above code snippet
I am getting this error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: This is because the `range(len(a))` gets created once, at the beginning, with the original size.  When you delete an element, that means that `i` is going to be referring to indexes that no longer exist.  A better way to do this is to build a new list with the numbers you want to keep.  The right way is to do `return sorted(list(set(a)))`.

Comment: @TimRoberts He does not want to use built-in helpers

Comment: Aren't `range` and `len` built-ins? The requirement is rather vague.

Comment: @sj95126 Technically speaking, `if` and `else` are also built-ins. I'm assuming he's doing an exercise and generally the goal is to create an algorithm of a specific function. His goal is to create an algorithm that removes duplicates in a list. `set` defeats the purpose of the exercise and is considered cheating. `range`, `len`, `if`, `else`, etc does not.

Comment: You are reading between the lines, @JeffreyRam.  The only hacky solution is to add `if i >= len(a):` / `break` after the first `for`.

Comment: @TimRoberts It sounds like we aren't in sync. To clarify, the title states "using 2 for loops without using inbuilt functions, temp, new list, enumerate" and you are suggesting to use `return sorted(list(set(a)))` which goes against what he wanted which is why I said he does not want to use built-in helpers.

Comment: OP needs to explain exactly **why** he needs to use two loops. What's the point? *for*, *range*, *del* and *print* are all built-ins. The question makes no sense.

Comment: I think his intentions are very clear: create an algorithm that removes duplicates from a list without the use of built-in helpers (excluding `for` `range`, basics operators, etc). The idea is exactly the same as any entry-level programming interviews, school homeworks, leetcode questions, algorithm exercises, etc.

Comment: @JeffreyRam OP needs to be absolutely clear about which built-ins he **can** and **cannot** use. I have no idea what you mean by "basics operators"

Comment: @Vlad I agree that he should personally clarify any confusion. As for my previous comment, I think it would help you understand if you're familiar with Leetcode or anything similar but aside from that, I am not capable of simplifying my explanation any further.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is that deleting a value shifts later values to the left. This messes with the next indexed value and the total length of the list. Your index `i` is based on the position and length of the original list but you are carving up the underlying list.

Suppose you did the process in reverse. Scan from the end to the front and only delete values that are past the next indexed value you will traverse. This way you won't affect the list items you haven't processed.

```
def remove_dup1(a):
    for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[i]
                break

s1 = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,8,7,8]
remove_dup1(s1)
print(s1)
```

If the builtin `range` and `len` anger you, you could remove them too

```
def remove_dup2(a):
    i = a.__len__() - 1
    while i:
        j = i - 1
        while j:
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[i]
                break
            j -= 1
        i -= 1

s1 = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,8,7,8]
remove_dup2(s1)
print(s1)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think it's worth pointing out that `a.__len__()` is exactly the same as `len(a)`.  I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying that the assignment is mostly silly.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Agreed, but I noticed the no-builtins comment above and thought I'd have a bit of fun with it. But that meant moving to while loops instead of for, so I am still in violation. But couldn't figure out how to do it with two fors (3 sure, but not 2).

Comment: @TimRoberts Generally, `len(a)` and `a.__len__()` are not *exactly* the same. You're always gonna get some extra checks with `len()` but not with `.__len__()`. But since `a` here is a built-in type, they are the same.